# how do i make my site wait to redirect when accessed remotely?

Tags: http, nginx

I have a simple webpage that hosts a image and some text but when i open my html file locally it waits ten seconds likt it should to redirect me to grabify but when i acess it from anywhere else with my nginx server it redirects immediatley, anyone know how to fix this. my page is below with a few things oubviouslt swapped for ploaceholders
`<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>image</title> <script> setTimeout(function() { window.location.replace("http://example.com/"); }, 3000); // Change the delay to 3000 milliseconds (3 seconds) </script> </head> <body> <h1>text</h1> <img src="image path" alt="image description" /> <p>Text</p> </body> </html>`

im not putting anything useful here

Comment: What you're saying doesn't make sense, and I can't duplicate it.  The redirect is handled by the browser.  The server is not involved.  Do you have this on a public site where we can see it for ourselves?